# Use Variable insted of Get-Date in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using `PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('ddMMyyyy')"` in batch script.

I want to use a variable instead of **Get-Date** function. Is it possible?

`ADate` is the variable name!

**Edited:**

As suggested, my script is:

```
For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('ddMMyyyy')"`
) Do Set "Freq=%%A"
```

`Adate` is simple string which comes from the file name, and has a value like `16112016`.

Comment: what is the format of your date variable ? simple string ? ISO8601 String ? timestamp ?

Comment: @RemyGrandin its a string "16112016" for 16 Nov 2016

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Use hard-coded date instead of calculating date based on today's date?

Comment: @vonPryz I am not aware of Power shell much.
Till time I was subtracting 7 days from systemdate.    But now have to use Variable and this variable is getting value from file name every time.

Comment: Instead of wasting time trying to include information in comments just edit your opening question and post the code _(psudo-code where necessary)_ to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you telling us that the code you are using does not do what you want it to do? Are you telling us that it is setting a variable to a date string which is seven days before today, but you want code to set a variable to a date which is seven days earlier that the created/modified or accessed date returned from a specific file's properties?

Comment: So, you're saying you want to read a date string from a file into a batch variable, and then use PowerShell to subtract 7 days from it? What does your input file look like, and how do you read it?

Comment: Why run a PowerShell command from a batch file? Just write the script in PowerShell and dispense with the batch file altogether. Things will suddenly start to get much less frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got my crystal ball and asked it: "What is the solution here?", and it replied: "Change

```
PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('ddMMyyyy')"
```

by

```
PowerShell "(Get-Date -Date '!Adate:~4!-!Adate:~2,2!-!Adate:~0,2!').AddDays(-7).ToString('ddMMyyyy')"
```

", but I have no idea what it is talking about! **`;)`**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [`for`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx) loop to get the output of an external command in a batch variable:

```batch
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%d in (`powershell "..."`) do set "adate=%%d"
echo %adate%
```

The `usebackq` and backticks are just so you don't need to escape the nested single quotes in your command string.

Comment: The OP edited the original question and added all your suggestions with not a single comment about that, so your answer have no sense now... **`:/`** (I downvoted the question and upvoted this answer)

Answer (score 0):

The following takes the last modified time from a known file's properties and creates a variable with a date seven days earlier, *(obviously changing `C:\Test\TestFile.ext` as necessary)*:

```bat
For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `PowerShell "((gi 'C:\Test\TestFile.ext').LastWriteTime).AddDays(-7).ToString('ddMMyyyy')"`
) Do Set "ADate=%%A"
```

**Edit**

The following example takes a date string with a known format, *(in this case provided in two variables)*. It then converts that string to a date object, subtracts seven days and sets it back to a string in the new `%ADate%` variable:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DateStr=16112016"
Set "DFormat=ddMMyyyy"

For /F UseBackQ %%A In (`Powershell^
 "([datetime]::ParseExact('%DateStr%','%DFormat%', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddDays(-7).ToString('%DFormat%')"
 `) Do Set "ADate=%%A"
Echo(%ADate%

Timeout -1
```

Comment: here instead of (Get-Date), I want to use Variable which is getting value from file Name.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, if my assumption is still incorrect please explain your task better.

Comment: Bingo...!    It is working as expected but I have question!   Why we are using "DFormat" what if we dont use it?

Comment: DFormat is the only way your script knows 1. What the format of the string you are reading is. 2. The format you want your variable string in. You need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of the powerShell command into a file and then read that file after that delete that temporary file.

```
    PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('ddMMyyyy')" >temp.txt
    set /p myVarDate= < date_Shell.txt
    echo Date from Shell %myVarDate%
    del temp.txt
```